# How to increase the limit of the Node.js querystring post request without Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I pass a data from the browser to my Node.js app and write the data into a file with this code:

**index.html**

```
<style>
iframe{display:none;}
</style>

<form method="post" target="iframe">
<textarea name="my_textarea">Some code with tags e.g. <p>text</p></textarea>
</form>
<button>SEND</button>
<iframe name="iframe"></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
});
</script>
```

**Node.js app**

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    querystring = require('querystring');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    fs.readFile(__dirname+'/index.html', function(err, indexPage) {
        if(!err) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.end(indexPage);
        }
    });

    if(req.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            var post = querystring.parse(body);
            if(post['my_textarea']) {
                var anotherPage = post['my_textarea'];
                fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/another.html', anotherPage, function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

}).listen(80, 'localhost');
```

After testing I found out that such request passes not more than 544 000 chars

Is it possible to specify somewhere or somehow my own limit and how to?

I know it's possible with Express like

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));
```

but I'm interested in how to do it without Express

ps. I send my own post request on local machine, so as I understand I don't need something like

```
...
body += data;
if(body.length > 1e6) {
    request.connection.destroy();
}
...
```

But if I still need it, please explain why

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this but this is for 1 Mb I think.
`1e6 === 1 * Math.pow(10, 6) === 1 * 1000000 ~~~ 1MB`

```
    req.on('data', function (data) {
          body += data;

        if (body.length > 1e6)
            req.connection.destroy();
    });
```

Comment: No, I meant there is already a limit about 544 000 chars somewhere inside of Node.js and I want to increase it

Comment: Well if you increse it you should be on the node team :D Good luck tho everything is possible.